# What is wrong with my date ranges in my CASE statement

Tags: sql

```
SELECT animalid,
CASE WHEN birthdate BETWEEN '12/31/21'  AND '12/31/2017' THEN 0
     WHEN birthdate BETWEEN '12/31/2017' AND '12/31/2014' THEN 100
     WHEN birthdate BETWEEN '12/31/2014' AND '12/31/2009' THEN 150
     WHEN birthdate BETWEEN '12/31/2009' AND '12/31/2006' THEN 200
     ELSE 300 END AS age_cost
FROM animals
```

When I process this all of my results get a cost of 300. What is not working in my CASE statement date ranges?

Comment: Side note: `CASE` **expression**, not statement. SQL knows no flow control statements at all.

Comment: [Edit] the question and tag the DBMS you're using.

Comment: Column birthdate data type?

Comment: Is a `'12/31/21'` valid birthdate value? Which year is supposed to mean?

Answer (score 1):

You have the end date first. You need to have the beginning of your range first.

On another note I would reconsider your use of BETWEEN. See this [blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) for more info on why.

```
SELECT
    animalid
    , CASE
          WHEN birthdate
               BETWEEN '12/31/2017' AND '12/31/2021'
              THEN 0
          WHEN birthdate
               BETWEEN '12/31/2014' AND '12/31/2017'
              THEN 100
          WHEN birthdate
               BETWEEN '12/31/2009' AND '12/31/2014'
              THEN 150
          WHEN birthdate
               BETWEEN '12/31/2006' AND '12/31/2009'
              THEN 200
          ELSE 300
          END AS age_cost
FROM
    animals;
```

Answer (score 1):

In some databases it's better to use [date literals](https://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/literals.php) in the YYYY-MM-DD format.

This will avoid a wrong interpretation of the date stamp.

F.e. The text '02/06/04'
Is it "February 6, 2004"?
Or "June 2, 2004"?
Or "April 6, 2002"?
Or "April 2, 2006"?

But '2004-06-02' will be understood correctly.

Also, the syntax for `BETWEEN` expects the first date to be lower than the second.

This would work in Postgresql & Sqlite :

```
SELECT animalid,
CASE WHEN birthdate BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2021-12-31' THEN 0
     WHEN birthdate BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2017-12-31' THEN 100
     WHEN birthdate BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2014-12-31' THEN 150
     WHEN birthdate BETWEEN '2007-01-01' AND '2009-12-31' THEN 200
     ELSE 300 END AS age_cost
FROM animals
```